# DefinitelyTyped ( import * as alias syntax doesn't work with export = class)

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

I m trying to create a DefinitelyTyped for a library, but when I import as alias
`import * as f from "foo";`
I'm having this message

> This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by
> turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its
> default export.

File index.d.ts

```
declare module "foo" {
  function test(): void;
  export = test;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding namespace it's work

```
declare module "foo" {
  function test(): void;
  namespace test{}
  export = test;
}
```